# Parent div not taking the background color

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have created a jquery mobile page with a Parent div with 2 child divs. I want a back round color for the whole div. So I`ve applied the backround color to the new1 Id. But I cannot able to apply. I am attaching my code here

```
<div id="new1">

       <div id = "c1">

       Welcome 
       </div>

    <div id = "c2">
       <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-role="fieldcontain" data-mini="true">

        <label for="select-choice-1" class="select"></label> 
                    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1" data-theme="a" >


                        <option value="select">Select</option> 
                        <option value="approve">Approve</option> 
                        <option value="reject">Reject</option>
                                        </select></fieldset>

       </div>

       </div>
```

CSS

```
#new1
{
background-color:#E32E18;
 position: relative;



}

#c1{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    margin-top: 5px;
margin-left:2px;

}



#c2{
    position: absolute;
    right:0;

}
```

Comment: What is the background color of the child divs?

Comment: Give height to `#new1` div

Comment: I want to apply the color to the whole div.. So I should apply it to the Parent div Isn`t? Since I am wrapping my child divs (c1,c2) into it..

Comment: @morphews If I do that, It will not look good in mobile phones.. Is there any other way bro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `new1` is `position:absolute` so its dimentions will not be applied to `new1`.

So you need to give a `height: xpx` to the container (`new`).

Another solution is to use `float` instead of positioning.

```
#new1
{
background-color:#E32E18;
position: relative;
}

#c1{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left:2px;
}

#c2{
    float: right;
}

.clearfix{*zoom:1}
.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{display:table;line-height:0;content:""}
.clearfix:after{clear:both}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rA6n7/2/).

The `clearfix` class is from [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

Comment: Hi Arun. When I open the "Clearfix" applied page in mobiles.. I`m getting a zoomed out view.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You cant give background color to something that don't have dimensions:

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/bPjLn/

```
#new1
{
   background-color:#E32E18;
   position: relative;
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: If I do give height and width.., It will not look good in mobile phones Isn`t??.. Is there any other way?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is how css works. You can't give it background color unless it has dimensions. Why do you think it want work on iOS?

Comment: I am creating an App for Ios, Android ( also for the tabs)...  Do u think it works for all resolutions bro?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Arun P Johny has an excellent solution below, try and improve it to work with jQM.